# Poor Performance on SPs and a Simple Query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

We have a staging DB (SQL Server 2012) which is only a VM and a clustered production DB (SQL Server 2008). They both have exactly the same DB schema. Staging has a little less data but not that much difference.

Recently I notice production DB is 4-5 times slower than staging when I run the same stored procedure on both. From the statistics IO I can see in general the production DB has a lot more logical reads.

They both have the same schema so it couldn't be an index issue. Is it possible there's something wrong with the memory on production?

**UPDATED**

I also notice that in client statistics, staging DB's "Wait time on server replies" is significantly lower (8-12) than production (160-170)

Comment: Maybe the statistics is stale?

Comment: Could fragmentation be an issue? Especially if you recently made one database and the other is long standing? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189858.aspx

Comment: rlb.usa, do you mean fragmentation in the indices? I rebuilt all the related indices but still to no avail.

Comment: Have checked the query execution plan

Comment: meda, the query plan shows nothing different. This is the exact same query that runs fast on staging but slow in production.

Comment: You mentioned specifically that your staging database is a VM, but didn't mention if you Prod database was virtual or physical.  If its physical, then this is an issue of apples and oranges.  My suggestions would be directed towards available memory and storage configurations.

Comment: You should add the execution plan (*as XML*) to this question. You could use pastebin.

Comment: I would run the query in [SQL Sentry Plan Explorer](http://www.sqlsentry.com/products/plan-explorer/sql-server-query-view) on both servers and compare **actual** (not estimated) execution plans. If the shape of the plan is the same, then check the IO and CPU stats. If both servers have the same plan and same number of reads, then the difference in performance could be caused by the hardware. Another variant - if production is under heavy load, then the query may be waiting for resources.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at it from a different angle: 
have you taken a good look at the actual execution plan to see if you can improve the performance of the query without taking into account that the query executes faster on the staging environment? (sometimes even small changes in data can lead to much slower queries)